# BerkeleyDB / Python (bsddb3) get list of removed files

Tags: python, python-2.7, berkeley-db, bsddb

I am using Python, BerkeleyDB and bsddb3 lib for an script which store many informations.
After use the same environment while months I get the following error :

```
bsddb3.db.DBNoSuchFileError
```

But I have many files in my environment. I don't know which file BerkeleyDB wants to open.

I tried **db_recover** but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea to find the missing file searched by BerkeleyDB ?

Comment: can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: Yes : CRITICAL     15:43:20     0d 0h 44m 21s     3/3     CRITICAL : [1586] - error : (2, 'No such file or directory')

Comment: look if there is no leap in db files number. It might be that a file was corrupted and sweaped by the OS.

Comment: Thank you, but my filenames don't increment. The files had generated by a script and there no way to detect a deletion. A BerkeleyDb can't give me the list of files which it tried to open ?

Comment: My recommendation is to ask on the mailling list: https://mailman.jcea.es/pipermail/pybsddb/